# C++ object instance variables are the same

Tags: c++

I have a class equivalent to this.  `Point` is an Object from the opencv library.

```
class MyClass {
private:
  double myVar;
  Point myPoint;
  vector<OtherClass> v;
public:
  MyClass(double x, Point p) : myVar(x), myPoint(p) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
      v.push_back(p);
    cout << &myVar << "," << &v << "," << &myPoint << "," << v.size() << endl;
  }
}
```

In `main`, I construct the objects like so

```
vector<MyClass> vec;
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
  vec.push_back(MyClass(2, Point(0,0)));
```

The output:

```
0x7fff5291ba58,0x7fff5291ba60,0x7fff5291ba70,5
0x7fff5291ba58,0x7fff5291ba60,0x7fff5291ba70,5
0x7fff5291ba58,0x7fff5291ba60,0x7fff5291ba70,5
0x7fff5291ba58,0x7fff5291ba60,0x7fff5291ba70,5
0x7fff5291ba58,0x7fff5291ba60,0x7fff5291ba70,5
```

When I stack allocate a vector of `MyClass`es and push instances of `MyClass` onto it, the output to the console is exactly the same.  I am not very experienced with C++, but I would expect that all the printed addresses would be different, as they reference different objects.  If I am incorrect and all the instances point to the same object, I would expect the size of the shared vector to continue to grow.  However, all the values printed remain exactly the same.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Not without seeing your _complete_, minimal testcase, no.

Comment: can you add the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't post the code that creates the instances of MyClass and pushes them onto a vector, but I suspect that they're being created in the same temporary location on the stack (so have all the same addresses), and then are copied (via vector::push_back) to their destination location.  If you add a member function that prints addresses of your member fields and then call that on the instances in your vector you'll see that the addresses are different.

Alternatively, if you use vector::emplace_back then it will create the object in the correct location of the vector and you'd see different addresses printed by your constructor.

Comment: Funny, I'm sure I wrote _exactly this_ several minutes earlier. Congratulations on the accept, I guess.

Comment: Ha! StackOverflow definitely had updating issues because when I submitted my answer there wasn't sample code showing the push_back (as you can tell from my answer).

Comment: @Hawkmoon: Yes, the question didn't have that when I submitted mine, either (as you can tell from my answer). Our answers are literally identical.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're using `emplace_back`, the location where you actually construct all these `MyClass` objects is in the function where you do the `push_back`ing, and presumably whatever method you use to do that results in a temporary `MyClass` first being constructed each time. The memory for each temporary constructed may be re-used for the next temporary constructed.

If you were add this output also for `MyClass`'s copy and move constructors then you would see the values that end up in the actual `MyClass` instances that live in your container.

*This answer is the best I can do without any code to examine.*